# React Native Expo pass expo vector icons as prop

Tags: react-native

How do I pass Expo vector icon type and name as prop to a component in React Native?

My Component:

```
const IconComponent = ({iconType, iconName}) =>{
    return (
        <set_type_here name={iconName} size={24} /> 
    )
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<IconComponent iconType='Feather' iconName='bell' size={24} />
<IconComponent iconType='AntDesign' iconName='mail' size={24} />
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but this is how I managed to pass Expo vector icons as props in a custom component using Typescript.

```
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export enum IconType {
  MatetrialIcon,
  FontAweomseIcon,
  Ionicon,
}


type CustomProps = {
   icon: {
     value: { type: IconType.MatetrialIcon, name: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.FontAweomseIcon, name: keyof typeof FontAwesome.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.Ionicon, name: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap };
     size: number;
   }
   
}


const CustomComponent = (props: CustomProps) => {
const { icon, ...otherProps } = props;

return 
  (
    <View style={styles.customIconStyle}>
      {icon.value.type === IconType.FontAweomseIcon && (
        <FontAwesome name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.MatetrialIcon && (
        <MaterialIcons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.Ionicon && (
        <Ionicons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
    </View>
  );

}
```